# Create Sub Report in Crystal Report of C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i make a Crystal report of product code which is displayed as user selection. if user select two product at a time from Listbox then in report both product and their rate is display only.

now, i want to add sub report for when user click on Particular Product their entire info. is displayed in sub report. there is a  product_code for product to identify.

so, how can i achieve the sub report link for display the info. that user click on main Report.

Please Help Me.

Thanks and Regards...
MItesh

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Right click on crystal Report Insert -> Sub Report -> Give a name of sub report and then and then go through wizard.

[image]

After completing the wizard go to link tab and add link between two reports usually its on a common column between two reports.

[image]

try this it will work for you.

Comment: if this question resolve your problem then mark this answer thanks